# Need C# Source Code relational diagram

Tags: c#, visual-studio, diagram

I recently took over a web application project written in Visual Studio 2008, C#. There was very little documentation from the previous guy. I know it uses master pages and the starting page is default.aspx. Although it may still be possible to trace the code manually (through LOTS of time and hard labor and still some more), I believe I'm not the first person facing such problem and there must be a more efficient method to getting an overview of how the entire solution files are related to each other.

***What I need*** is a high level diagram that gives an overview of which page/control is calling another page/control, etc... and how they're all related will be very helpful.

Anyone know how this is done?

Thank you!

Btw, my previous experience was mainly Visual Foxpro...

Edit:

Thank you Aim Kai, Fernando, and Daniel Brückner for the lead. I've download and installed the trial for both NDepend and Reflector. Tested them and must say they're both excellent products. NDepend seems like the more powerful product, and may be worth the money. Anyway, I'll play around with both some more before deciding. Thanks again and cheers!

Answer (score 7):

NDepend is a very good tool.. This may help as well.. [.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) by Red gate with some of the following plugins...

http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins

Answer (score 4):

You could try some [Reflector's](http://reflector.red-gate.com/) add ins, like [SequenceViz](http://www.codeplex.com/sequenceviz/Wiki/View.aspx?title=ReflectorPlugin) and [AutoDiagrammer](http://www.codeproject.com/csharp/AutoDiagrammer.asp). See the full list [here](http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins).

Answer (score 2):

[NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) comes to the rescue. But it targets large code bases and costs some money.

Answer (score 1):

If you can take a copy of the project, and load it up on Visual Studio 2010, there is a "Generate Sequence Diagram" option at the method level -- you can see the call tree for calls below the method that you are on.

Comment: Hi JMarsch, I loaded up VS 2010 Ultimate RC but couldn't find what you suggested even after playing around with it. Thanks for the suggestion away, cheers!

Comment: I haven't tried it with an ASPX application, so maybe that's the problem.  Here's where to find it:  In the Code Editor, right-click on a method name.  In the context menu "Generate Sequence Diagram..." is the fourth item from the top.